# CSS Can't figure out why div disappears

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to make some tabs for a search bar, by using 2 images, inside 2 seperate divs, but for some reason it will only show one image. One or the other. If I comment out the home-searchbar-school id from the css, the professor tab shows, otherwise only the school will show, and it shows up where the professor tab should be. When I look to see where the divs are in google chrome's dev helper, it shows them in the right spot, so Im kind of stumped.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="home-searchbar">
    <div id="home-searchbar-tabs">
        <div id="home-searchbar-professor" class="home-searchbar-tab">

        </div>
        <div id="home-searchbar-school" class="home-searchbar-tab">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home-searchbar-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#home-searchbar{
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 115px;
    width: 980px;
    background-color: green;    
}

#home-searchbar-tabs{
    float: left;
    width: 980px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: red;
}

.home-searchbar-tab{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 190px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
}

#home-searchbar-professor{
    background: url('../img/searchtabs.png') 0 0  no-repeat;
}

#home-searchbar-professor{
    background: url('../img/searchtabsinactive.png') 0 -64px  no-repeat;
}

#home-searchbar-container{
    float: left;
    width: 980px;
    height: 83px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

the images are sprites, those are working correctly so I'll only upload one of them. 
The other image is the same just different color scheme.

Also a random little question, is that good style for having a class and id in the divs? I'm still learning about CSS so was wondering if that was the correct way/optimal way to use both in a div?

Thanks a lot for any help or advice you can give!

[image]

Comment: Try to add a two image separately in a home-searchbar-professor div and hide a image using css property display: none or visibility: hidden. Its a correct way you can use both class and id in the same div

Comment: both background css uses the same id, #home-searchbar-professor

Comment: That was it Ark, thanks, I feel so dumb now.

Comment: @Ark, Since you answered it, if you want the rep go ahead and leave an answer please! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the answer:
"both background css uses the same id, #home-searchbar-professor"

ty the rep, and ur css is ok btw

Answer (score 0):

```
#home-searchbar-professor{
    background: url('../img/searchtabs.png') 0 0  no-repeat;
}

#home-searchbar-professor{
    background: url('../img/searchtabsinactive.png') 0 -64px  no-repeat;
}
```

both are called `home-searchbar-professor`, so rename one to `home-searchbar-school`